# оптимизация кода в yii2

Tags: yii2, оптимизация

У меня две связанные таблицы, которые я вывожу через gridview в представлении. В модели я использую жадную загрузку. Однако в отдельно взятых столбцах, формируемых в `columns => [...]` у меня неоднократно используются дублированные запросы в бд.

В итоге я получаю такую картину:

```
SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE `client_id`=293
F:\OSPanel\domains\es.loc\common\models\User.php:1229
F:\OSPanel\domains\es.loc\frontend\views\seller\crm\**lid.php:79**
F:\OSPanel\domains\es.loc\backend\widgets\GridView\GridView.php:51

SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE `client_id`=293
F:\OSPanel\domains\es.loc\common\models\User.php:1229
F:\OSPanel\domains\es.loc\frontend\views\seller\crm\**lid.php:104**
F:\OSPanel\domains\es.loc\backend\widgets\GridView\GridView.php:51
```

и так столько раз сколько в view у меня встречаются записи типа

```
User::clientId($model->id)->event[0]->next_date
```

В дебаге я вижу, что один и тот же запрос в базу у меня дублируется 5 раз. Как я понимаю это не правильно и я должен убрать этот косяк.

Каким образом я могу обратиться в базу один раз, чтоб в таблице gridview в пределах одной строки для формирования данных в столбцах у меня вместо пяти запросов формируемых через

```
User::clientId($model->id)
```

получился 1 запрос, например при первом использовании, и во всех последующих столбцах этой строки использовался этот результат?

метод выглядит так:

```
public function clientId($id) {
        $res = User::find()->with('event')->where(['id' => $id])->all();
        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код в котором вы формируете `GridView`